# Issues running simple Spring Boot App in IntelliJ Community version

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am starting a demo spring boot app using IntelliJ Community 2019.3, however I am getting errors even launching just a simple demo app:

**ERRORS:**

```
/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java
Error:(3, 32) java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
Error:(4, 46) java: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
Error:(6, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
Error:(10, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

I have googled and looked at potential other solutions BUT none of them seem to be working for me
my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help or potential solutions please. Thanks!

Comment: Can you build by Maven from a command line? Use `mvn clean install` command in project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Reload** action in Maven tool window for the IDE to download the needed dependencies for the project:

[image]